# How to direct dynamic route to same page in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

I have 2 links like this and both lead to 1 page, what should I do?

`path 1: '/:language/:type/:name' ("en/doctor/balestra")`

`path 2: '/:type/:name' ("doctor/balestra")`

If not, the language will default to `"en"`

I tried using rewrite, but nextjs doesn't accept

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this (I assume you are using Next.js v10.0.0 or higher and using built in i18n routing)

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ["en", "fr", "de"],
        defaultLocale: "en",
    },

    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/:type/:name",
                permanent: true,
                destination: "/profile/:type/:name",
            },
        ];
    },
};
```

this will redirect both `/aa/bb` and `/en/aa/bb` to `/profile/aa/bb`. Note [there is no prefix for default locale](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18419) (in this case en), but other locales will be prefixed i.e `/fr/aa/bb` will redirect to `/fr/profile/aa/bb`.